# Как сохранить изображение полученное из get запроса к API

Tags: python, get

Пытаюсь разобраться в использовании открытого `API` карт `HERE`.

```
import  requests
api_url = 'https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview'

params = {
    'app_id': 'my_app_id',
    'app_code': 'my_app_code'
}

res = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
print(res.headers)
```

Вот вывод:

```
    {'Date': 'Mon, 28 Jan 2019 23:41:59 GMT', 
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '31174', 
    'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx-clojure',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Forwarded-For': 'my_app_code',
 'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 28 Jan 2019 23:41:59 GMT',
     'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=2592000', 
    'Expires': 'Wed, 27 Feb 2019 23:41:59 GMT',
     'X-Served-By': 'i-0ada5d38a4ed13ae9.eu-west-1a',
     'X-NLP-IRT': 'D=119988'}
```

Вижу, что это `jpeg` **картинка**. **Как мне её сохранить**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша картинка в строке байтов `res.content`.

Чтобы сохранить её в файл, например как `image.jpg`, вы можете применить

```
import io

with io.open('image.jpg', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(res.content)
```